# How to assign the value in C#?

Tags: c#, assign

I'm investigating C# and some code where the string:

```
sheet.Cells[startRowIndexHeader, 11].Value = _currentRowPowerContext.HighVoltageSubstationContext.LowSide.Cub.TryGetCaption();
```

is inserting some text value in some excel cell.
When I tried to change this Cub by the string:

```
currentRowPowerContext.HighVoltageSubstationContext.LowSide.Cub.AttributeCaption = "My value";
```

I recived the message

> Object reference does not point to an instance of an object

How to change the Cub value?

By the way the code of TryGetCaption() functions which I found in this script:

```
public static string TryGetCaption(this ClassifierItem value)
{
    return value == null ? null : value.AttributeCaption;
}

public static string TryGetCaption(this DirectRoute value)
{
    var routeAsIp = value as CustomTCPClientRoute;
    if (routeAsIp != null)
        return string.Format("{0}: {1}", routeAsIp.AttributeHostOrIP, routeAsIp.AttributePort);
    return value == null ? null : value.Caption;
}

public static string TryGetCaption(this EnumerationItem value)
{
    return value == null ? null : value.Caption;
}
```

Comment: So what part of currentRowPowerContext.HighVoltageSubstationContext.LowSide.Cub.AttributeCaption is null ?

Comment: Do a null check: `if (obj.Cub != null) obj.Cub.AttributeCaption = " ... ";`

Comment: Notice that those extension methods do a `null` check first. You should do the same... :)

Comment: Also they aren't following the typical `TryGet` pattern, which returns a `bool` indicating success and sets an `out` parameter to the value (or the default on failure). Those methods above should be named something like `GetCaptionOrDefault`

Answer (score 0):

`currentRowPowerContext.HighVoltageSubstationContext.LowSide.Cub` is null so you can not assign value to its properties. Check if it is null or not before assigning:

```
if(currentRowPowerContext.HighVoltageSubstationContext.LowSide.Cub != null)
currentRowPowerContext.HighVoltageSubstationContext.LowSide.Cub.AttributeCaption = "My value";
```

Comment: Thank you @Ashkan! If Cub is null so why the excel cell is not null and contains the value from `_currentRowPowerContext.HighVoltageSubstationContext.LowSide.Cub.TryGetCaption()` ?